# What does cpsr [ EL=0 ] means in gdb?

Tags: gdb, cpu-registers, arm64, flags

I know current program status register aka `cpsr` is used to as flag register. But I didn't understand what gdb is trying give info about `[ EL=0 ]`.

Here is my display

```
cpsr           0x80200000          [ EL=0 SS N ]
```

I only know basic flags such as `V` means overflow and another flags like `C N Z`

And the other flags such as `SS` i didn't find it in documentation of arm.

Comment: According to the [gdb code](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/features/aarch64-core.xml;h=ab54a37b113c4e716656e15293b82e8d35b89186;hb=HEAD#l50) `EL` means `Exception Level`. See also [the ARM docu](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/a/Overview-of-AArch64-state/Process-State).

Comment: Searching for `spsr_el1` will give you more useful results.

Comment: @ssbssa: Would you like to make that an answer?